# How to add data to in table of google doc APİ | How to add table on docs Google APİ

Tags: go, google-docs, google-docs-api

First of all soory my bad english.
I wanted to create a table in the docs and write data into it.
you can see my code

```
data := [][]string{
        {"Ad", "Soyad", "no"},
        {"İkram", "mert", "1"},
        {"berk", "dert", "2"},
    }

    values := make([][]interface{}, len(data))
    for i, row := range data {
        values[i] = make([]interface{}, len(row))
        for j, cell := range row {
            values[i][j] = cell
        }
    }

    requests := make([]*docs.Request, 0)

    // Insert table //just 3x3  add table. not wrote data into table
    requests = append(requests, &docs.Request{
        InsertTable: &docs.InsertTableRequest{
            Rows:                 int64(len(values)),
            Columns:              int64(len(values[0])),
            EndOfSegmentLocation: &docs.EndOfSegmentLocation{},
        },
    })
batchUpdateReq := &docs.BatchUpdateDocumentRequest{
        Requests: requests,
    }
```

this code just give me e table 3x3
how to add data into my table

how to add data into my table

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Unfortunately I didn't succeed. Do I have a chance to do it the normal way, I wonder if I just solve this problem, I seem to take care of the others.`, my library uses googleapis for golang. If your `the normal way` is to use googleapis, my library is a wrapper for managing the tables using the normal way. But from your reply, it seems that my library is not suitable for your situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer because I don't want to confuse other users. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I apologize for my poor skill.